# Enter data into text boxes, save them to html table

Tags: javascript, html

[image: This is design pagee]

Here i want to enter data into the text boxes after clicking submit button, insert the textbox data into html table . In  table record must have edit button, after clicking edit button that particular record  get into the text boxes and update to the html table.
here i have used inserCell()(new cell)I am not able to do after that. please replay

```js
function addrow()
{
    var name = document.getElementById("txtbox1").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("txtbox2").value;
    var id = document.getElementById("txtbox3").value;
    var age = document.getElementById("txtbox4").value;
    var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
    var row = table.insertRow(1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    cell1.innerHTML = name;
    cell2.innerHTML = password;
    cell3.innerHTML = id;
    cell4.innerHTML = age;
    cell5.innerHTML = "new cell";
}


//html design page
```

```html
<head>
   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <table class="auto-style1">
        <tr>
            <td>NAME</td>
            <td><input type="text" value="" id="txtbox1" /></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>PASSWORD</td>
            <td><input type="text" value="" id="txtbox2" /></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td><input type="text" value="" id="txtbox3" /></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>AGE</td>
            <td><input type="text" value="" id="txtbox4" /></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="button" VALUE="SUBMIT" id="BTNSUBMIT" onclick="addrow()"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="mytable" border="1" >
        <tr>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>PASSWORD</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>AGE</th>
         
        </tr>

    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: looks like you could use a tutorial on this type of stuff, there are many things I would change about the way you structured your code, for example, you should use an array to keep each instance of a "cell" instead of making a variable for each one.

Comment: ok, here is a real suggestion: if you want the button press to add to a table the easiest way to do this is to use a library like knockout.js, they have good tutorials and it saves you a ton of work in terms of html maintenance. The concept is called data-binding or also MVVM

Comment: can you please send me the code

Comment: " they have good tutorials ". You have a search engine. Good luck. This isn't a free write-my-code or make-me-a-demo site. If you have some code you want fixing, then great, but you seem to want us to add more features to your site from nothing. And as mentioned, you're doing it in a very laborious way and probably the quickest thing to do is start again using a framework. You can find out how to use them...from the tutorials, not to mention if you search there will no doubt be many previous questions on StackOverflow and elsewhere. If you try, but get stuck, ask a new question about it

Comment: a little harsh but well put.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to manage html from javascript is to use a data-binding library such as knockout js.

Here is a working example of what you want to achieve:

https://jsfiddle.net/up14yz68/

Open that link to see a live demonstration with functionality implemented and all.

the code, html:

```
<table class="auto-style1">
  <tbody  data-bind="foreach: fields">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: title"></td>
      <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: value"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="button" VALUE="SUBMIT" data-bind="click: addRow"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="mytable" border="1" >
  <tr data-bind="foreach: fields">
    <th data-bind="text: name"></th>
  </tr>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: rows">
    <tr data-bind="foreach: $data">
      <td data-bind="text: value"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

the code, js:

```
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.rows = ko.observableArray([
    [
      {title: "name", value: "Santiago"},
      {title: "password", value: "Pa55w0rd"},
      {title: "id", value: "100255"},
      {title: "age", value: "28"}
    ], [
      {title: "name", value: "Stack"},
      {title: "password", value: "overflow"},
      {title: "id", value: "108888"},
      {title: "age", value: "13"}
    ]
  ]);

    self.fields = [
    {title: "name", value: ko.observable("John")},
    {title: "password", value: ko.observable("secret123")},
    {title: "id", value: ko.observable("10001")},
    {title: "age", value: ko.observable("50")},
  ];

    self.addRow = function() {
    var newRow = [];
    self.fields.forEach(function(field) {
        newRow.push({title: field.title, value: field.value()});
      field.value("");
    });
    self.rows.push(newRow);
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Feel free to poke around the fiddle to understand what is going on. You can learn to use knockout at their website, they have good tutorials.

There are other alternatives for data-binding out there, like angular, but I feel knockout is very lean and unobtrusive with the rest of the application.

Comment: I know, the original question was to vague, so answers will vary greatly. but I feel like many people might find this question from google and would want a quick example that they can grab and modify for quick results.